# Files for puppet agents

Tags: puppet

How to manage files which are not static but dynamic. Different services can have files which needs different values based on their characteristics! 
Like ssh configuration file the listening interface should the IP of the machine (agent), in the same way how can I use hostname ?
and if I have keepalived how will I provide different priority numbers to the two agent machine with the same file ???

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage files as templates, more info on puppetlabs: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html

Comment: Please don't answer with "go read that link". If that link ever stops working your answer will become useless. Please expand to include relevant details directly in your answer.